# Php json _decode function returns null on long data

Tags: php, json

I pull data from a json file on the remote server. This json file has 97000 Lines of json code. It returns null when I decode the Json file. When I debug the Json errors, I see that there is no error.

Json file : https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/");
$json =  json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json); // Return Null
```

But when I decode another json file there is no error

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://randomuser.me/api/");
$json =  json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json); // Return Array
```

Could this be due to the size of the data?

Thanks for advance

Comment: When I check for errors (`json_last_error_msg()`), I get "Syntax error"…

Comment: If there is an error, you should include it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file starts with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is a syntax error for `json_decode`.

Ultimately this should be fixed by the host, as a workaround you can strip the first three bytes:

```
if (substr($json, 0, 3) == "\xEF\xBB\xBF") {
    $json = substr($json, 3);
}
```